# Spark - avoiding shuffles with similar (but slightly different) joins

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a series of Dataframes being joined together with slightly different sets of columns

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("order_id", "customer_id"))
.join(df3, Seq("order_id"))
.join(df3, Seq("order_id", "month"))
...
```

All the joins include `order_id` but some joins include other columns as well.

Now, if `order_id` is much higher cardinality than the other columns what would make sense is to partition everything on `order_id` so we don't end up shuffling other results on different combinations of `customer_id` and `month`.

is there a way to get Spark to keep everything partitioned on `customer_id` alone?

Answer (score 1):

In relation to:

> is there a way to get Spark to keep everything partitioned on `customer_id` alone?

No, there is not, that is not how Spark works. Basically, the left side and the right side of the join need to be (re-)partitioned using the same partitioner and are done in sets of JOINs.

Running an `.explain` will reveal that. It's not an ORACLE database.

Here is a good read on joins and shuffling effects: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-art-of-joining-in-spark-dcbd33d693c

```
val res = df1.join(df2, Seq("order_id", "firstname")).join(df3, Seq("order_id"))
res.explain(true)
```

reveals:

[image]

As you can see, there are definite steps for each JOIN pair.